# Expected primary expression error

Tags: solidity, error

I have this error:

> Expected primary expression.

This is the code :

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17; 

contract Adoption {

address[16] public adopters;

// Adopter un animal
function adopt(uint petId) public returns (uint) { 
  require(petId >= 0 &amp,&amp; petId <= 15); 
  adopters[petId] = msg.sender; 
  return petId;
 } 

// La liste des propriétaires
function getAdopters() public view returns (address[16]) {
  return adopters;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax error can easily be fixed by just changing `&amp,&amp;` to &&.

However, this will then give you a call stack size error, since you cannot return an object as large as your adopters array. You should ideally have a `getAdopters(uint256 id)` function that returns just one adopter.